# Label on view does not change text on initial load

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a label on the top of my view. After you enter a string into a text field on a different view, this string is saved into `NSUserDefaults` upon clicking a `UIButton`. This `UIButton` also segues into my `UITabBarController`. I want the label at the top of the shown tab to change to the string saved from the previous view. All I have at the moment is this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *username = [self.prefs stringForKey:@"Username"];
    self.userNameLabel.text = username;
}
```

This is in the `viewcontroller.m` file for the first tab in the tab bar controller.

The issue is that when the segue happens, the label is left blank; however, when I change to the second tab and back to the first, the label is not accurately changed. I'm sure it's a simple fix, it is just over my head.

Comment: have you checked the [self.prefs stringForKey:@"Username"]; value?

Comment: Can you see the string in the log? Are you sure it is not nil in other words... Try this and try hard coding the text of the label to anything, just to make sure this works..

Comment: So, the string did end up null, so where would I go from here?

Comment: Did you synchronize defaults after setting the string?

Comment: Yes, I did. It was synchronized after saving the string.

Comment: Add your code where you synchronized your string